# Реализовать что-то типо рулетки?

Tags: javascript

Необходимо подогнать нужный item-active в середину блока по клику на кнопку, решение снизу в принципе работает, так как проходит +- одинаковой кол-во времени, но если переключиться на другую вкладку, то в центре окажется абсолютно непонятный и ненужный блок, есть какие-нибудь идеи?

```js
function randomInteger(min, max) {
      var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min)
      rand = Math.round(rand);
      return rand;
    }
    $('.log').click(function(event) {
      var start = Date.now(); 

      var timer = setInterval(function() {
        
        var timePassed = Date.now() - start;
        if (timePassed >= randomInteger(7020, 7120)) {
          clearInterval(timer);
          return;
        }
        
        draw(timePassed);

      }, 20);


      function draw(timePassed) {
        $('.roulete').css('left', -timePassed / 0.5 + 'px')
      }
    });
```

```css
.roulete{
        position: relative;
        width: 15220px;
        height: 140px;
        left: 0px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        background: white;
      }

      .item{
        position: relative;
        left: 0; 
        width: 190px;
        height: 140px;
        background: green;
        margin:  0 5px;
        float: left;
        font-size: 2em;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 134px;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;  
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="roulete">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>
        <div class="item item-active">6</div>
        <div class="item">7</div>
        <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
<div class="log">OPEN</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно зачем в вашем примере используется RNG, Если вам нужно отцентровать активный блок, вот:

```js
$('.log').click(function(event) {


  var r = $('.roulete');
  r.animate({
    "left": -(r.children('.item-active').position().left - window.innerWidth/2 + r.children('.item-active').width()/2)
  })


});
```

```css
body
{
margin: 0;
}
.roulete {
  position: relative;
  width: 15220px;
  height: 140px;
  left: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: white;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  width: 190px;
  height: 140px;
  background: green;
  margin: 0 5px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 134px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="roulete">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item item-active">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
<div class="log">OPEN</div>
```

В случае если вам нужна "Рулетка" то сначала выберите случайный активный элемент:

```js
$('.log').click(function(event) {


  var r = $('.roulete');
  var res = parseInt(Math.random()*r.children('.item').length);
  r.children('.item').eq(res).addClass('item-active')
  r.animate({
    "left": -(r.children('.item-active').position().left - window.innerWidth/2 + r.children('.item-active').width()/2)
  })
  r.children('.item-active').removeClass('item-active');


});
```

```css
body
{
margin: 0;
}
.roulete {
  position: relative;
  width: 15220px;
  height: 140px;
  left: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: white;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  width: 190px;
  height: 140px;
  background: green;
  margin: 0 5px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 134px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="roulete">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
<div class="log">OPEN</div>
```